# How can I prevent to use a variable inside a php request?

Tags: php, mysql

For security reasons I would like to change this working mySQL request...

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

$pdo = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM $value WHERE id = ?;");  
$pdo->execute(array($id));
```

...into...

```
$pdo = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ? WHERE id = ?;");  
$pdo->execute(array($value,$id));
```

But I get an error message:

> Syntax error or access violation: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax;

Comment: You cant bind table names,even if you use variable interpolation it will be a security risk

Comment: If only that were possible.

Comment: Since you have a finite number of tables in your database, keep a whitelist of possible names.  (You can query the DB to generate this list dynamically.)  For the user input, compare the given table name to the list.  If there's a match, use the value from the list.  (If there's no match, return an error to the user.)  It's a bit more roundabout than using a parameter, but prevents you from executing user input as SQL.

Comment: Ok, good idea. Sad, that this is not possible